# Rules for receiting a surah during salat

Tags: quran, salat, surah, ayah

If I look at youtube, an imam may recite a surah X from ayah a to b, or surah Y from ayah c to d during a salat. For example Al Baqarah from ayah 153 - 158, Humazah from ayah 1 - 9, or Ash Shu'ara from ayah 86 - 104, etc. Where do we learn this ? How do we know that we can recite Al Baqarah 153 - 158, and not 157 - 159, or 151 - 155 ? If I look at either the quran.com or quranwbw.com, there is no symbol whatsoever that  indicate it.

Answer (score 0):

In salah you first recite Surah al-Fatihah. After that technically you can recite *any* other surah or any verses from any surah. There are guidelines in the madhabs on which surahs\verses are recommended ([al-mufassal](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/143301/definition-of-al-mufassal-in-the-quraan-and-the-long-and-short-soorahs-of-al-mufassal)), or for the length of recitation (such as 1-3 verses), or for reciting verses in-order and reciting such that the meaning is completed. However there are no restrictions on which verses from the Quran can be recited.

> فاقرءوا ما تيسر من القرآن
>
> So recite what is easy [for you] of the Qur'an.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 73:20](https://quran.com/73/20?translations=20)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @UmH for your answer. If I understand correctly, Al Baqarah from ayah 153 - 158, Humazah from ayah 1 - 9, or Ash Shu'ara from ayah 86 - 104, etc, is a division / breakdown within that respective surah. Unfortunately that division / breakdown is not visible on quran.com or quranwbw.com. Is there any site which shows that division / breakdown ?